# VBscript RecordCount property

Tags: vbscript, ado, recordset

I am newbie in VBScript and I've come across with the following problem. I want get data from sql server db and to allow RecordCount properties. Next code get data but RecordCount is disabled. How can I enable this properties

```
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=BUG\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=test;user id ='sa';password='111111'"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
myCommand.CommandText = ("select * from klienci k where k.indeks = " & oferty(16))
Set klienci = myCommand.Execute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't change the cursor type when using the `Execute` method of the `Command` object, and you can't change the cursor type after you retrieved the recordset. Something like this might work, though:

```
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=BUG\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=test;user id ='sa';password='111111'"

Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING

query = "select * from klienci k where k.indeks = " & oferty(16)

Set klienci = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
klienci.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
klienci.CursorType     = 3 'adOpenStatic
klienci.LockType       = 1 'adLockReadOnly

klienci.Open query, myConn
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a VBScript issue- I think it is an ADO issue.

I think you are using a default forward-only cursor which won't work with recordcount.

I think you should stick a cursortype=adOpenStatic in there but I'm having a little trouble determining if you are specifying a recordset object -  klienci?

If so try 
    klienci.cursortype=adOpenStatic